# Скрыть JavaScript код в исходном коде страницы

Tags: html, javascript

Есть ли способы сокрытия JavaScript-кода на WEB-страницах ?

Comment: просто не добавляйте код. И его никто не увидит.

Comment: Так не пойдет. В моем случае JS необходим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте какой-нибудь обфускатор JavaScript, конкретную прогу рекомендовать не буду, в интернете полно информации по этому поводу.

Comment: Если выполняемый код действительно имеет такую важность, то лучше его выполнять на сервере. Потраченное время на обфускацию может себя не оправдать.

Comment: А что за обфускатор?

Comment: Ну, для примера посмотрите http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx

Comment: КЛАСС! И где вы раньше только были с этим обфускатором !?

Comment: И вот, например: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

Answer (score 2):

Как именно скрыть я не подскажу, но возможно вам нужно отделить нужную часть кода и перенести ее на сервер, а легковесный скрипт оставить на странице и общаться с сервером по AJAX?

Comment: Может даже так...

Comment: Просто, на мой взгляд, это наиболее гуманный способ.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript должен выполнять бразуер - поэтому скрыть его в принципе нельзя. Можно минимизировать - это снизит понятность кода, но он все равно будет открыт.

По хорошему то, что не нужно видеть пользователям - нужно выполнять на сервере.

В любом случае браузер должен выполнять нешифрованный код, значит злоумышленник (грамотный) 100% его сможет увидеть, если захочет.

Comment: Ну Js особой опасности при изменении не несет. Самое страшное, что можно сделать базовым JS - стырить кукисы =)

Answer (score 1):

JS выполняется браузером - поэтому адекватных способов скрыть нет (кроме какой-нибудь кодировки - но это уже на уровне маразма, имхо).

Comment: Спасибо, учту =)

Answer (score 1):

Вы ищите как скрыть, я ищу того кому бы это было нужно :)))))

В принципе, конечно, скрыть то, что передано в браузер нельзя, но практически можно.

Вопрос:

Есть ли способы сокрытия JavaScript-кода на WEB-страницах ?

Ответ:

Есть способы сокрытия JavaScript-кода на WEB-страницах !!!

http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/50004-spor-o-skrytii-kontenta.html

Comment: И как им пользоваться. Там только написано, что возможно...вот сделать бы так, как они говорят...

Answer (score 0):

Для защиты от простого копирования исходника лучше всего использовать обфускатор ([вот](http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/), кстати, тоже неплохой сервис). Причём можно встроить в шифруемый скрипт проверку location.href. А пытаться защитить код от профессионалов бессмысленно... Сейчас (исключительно ради научного интереса =)) посмотрел сервис, который предлагал Van... Достал код страницы регистрации минуты за две, что ещё раз подтверждает, что полностью скрыть код невозможно.

Comment: Ну да =) Все, уже все выясниось....вопрос можно закрывать.